# Error in django1.5 Reverse for 'lebay_user_home' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: python, django, web

i'm trying to update a project i found on web, called 'little ebay', from django 1.2 to 1.5. 
I cannot solve this problem... a NoReverseMatch error  : Reverse for 'lebay_user_home' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

This is my urls.py file

```
url(r'^profile/user/(?P<user_id>\d+)/$', lebay_views.view_user_profile, name='lebay_view_user_profile'),
```

this is the view i use

```
def view_user_profile(request, user_id):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

    return render_to_response('lebay/view_user_profile.html', {
        'user': user,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and this is the line of the template that gives me the error

```
<a href="{% url 'com:lebay_view_user_profile' request.user.user.pk %}">View Profile</a>
```

Please help me guys, i'm going mad with that. Thanks

Comment: I don't think the URL with name `lebay_view_user_profile` is causing issue as in the error the URL name is `lebay_user_home`??

Comment: i'm posting lebay_user_home

Comment: do you have a namespace set for the app `lebay_views` in `ROOT_URL_CONF` ?

Comment: ok, unfortunately i can't post the view, i've have to wait cause the forum rules.
Yes when i imported the views i wrote " as lebay_views" so i can call them in that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the url of lebay_user_home

```
url(r'^home/$', lebay_views.view_user_home, name='lebay_user_home'),
```

and this is the related view

```
@login_required
def view_user_home(request):
item__status=AUCTION_ITEM_STATUS_RUNNING)
won_auctions = AuctionEvent.objects.filter(winning_bidder=request.user.user,  item__status=AUCTION_ITEM_STATUS_SOLD)
listable_items = Item.objects.filter(seller=request.user.user, status=AUCTION_ITEM_STATUS_IDLE)

return render_to_response('lebay/view_user_home.html', {
    'current_auctions': current_auctions,
    'won_auctions': won_auctions,
    'listable_items': listable_items,
}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong `request.user.user.pk` it should be `request.user.pk`:

```
{% url 'com:lebay_view_user_profile' request.user.pk %}
```

For more information check [HttpRequest.user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user)

Comment: The program is divided in only 3 files, should i post them?